# Filling a texture pattern over another texture in unity

Tags: android, opengl-es, unity-game-engine, shader

I am trying to create a character customization in unity for android. Now the scenario is that i have a dress model which is a texture2D, also a number of patterns and colors that the user can apply on this model of dress. Now when the user applies a pattern on to the dress i need to change the dress to be displayed in that pattern. For color i was able to change the rgb value to the desired color value. But for the pattern I will need to traverse through each pixel of the dress and apply the patterns corresponding color to the pixel of the dress. I achieved this by the following code.

```
    IEnumerator Print() {
    Texture2D tex = DressTexture;
    Color32[] DressColor = tex.GetPixels32();   
    Color32[] PatternColor = PatternTexture.GetPixels32();
    int j = 0;
    Texture2D NewDressPattern = new Texture2D(tex.width, tex.height, TextureFormat.ARGB32, false);
    for(int i = 0; i < DressColor.Length; i++) {
        if(DressColor[i].a != 0) {
            DressColor[i] = PatternColor[j];
            j++;
            if(j == PatternColor.Length - 1) {
                j = 0;
            }
        }
        else {
            j = 0;
        }
        yield return null;
    }
    NewDressPattern.SetPixels32(DressColor);
    NewDressPattern.Apply();
    Debug.Log("texture created");
    Sprite spr = Sprite.Create(NewDressPattern, new Rect(0, 0, tex.width, tex.height), Vector2.zero);
    Debug.Log("sprite created");
    sprite.sprite = spr;
}
```

Now the problem is this operation is too slow to complete. Any suggestions for a better way to achieve this would be really helpful. Also i am not aware of shaders much.

Answer (score 0):

Texture operations always require some time consuming processing. There are workarounds you can do to minimize the impact on user. Like doing calculations multithreaded or nonblocking (I think that's what you are doing right now). But they will only minimize the problem, won't solve it.

You did not mention if the texture used in a 2D environment as a sprite or used on a 3D model.

**For a 2D game:**

What I would do is I would use a separate sprite for each object. Then I would overlap sprites and the result will exactly be like what you are trying to do above.

**For a 3D model:**

You can use some simple shaders to overlap multiple textures. Just Google it and you will have plenty of examples. Simple shaders like these does not require rocket science knowledge :)

Comment: Thanks for the answers @Can Baycay. The game uses sprites. Creating separate sprites for  each pattern is not possible as this will increase the build size. If i have 10 dresses and 5 patterns, i will have to make 50 sprites which i think will not be good.

Comment: Then it's better to do it using shaders. @gamedevelopmentgerm 's answer is a good start I think.

Answer (score 0):

Also, render-to-texture technique can be used to pre-render multiple texture passes. For example, the code below uses built-in "Diffuse Detail" shader to combine **Texture2D** objects and put result in **RenderTexture**:

```
public RenderTexture PreRenderCustomDressTexture(int customTextureWidth, int customTextureHeight, Texture2D pattern1, Texture2D pattern2)
{
    RenderTexture customDressTexture = new RenderTexture( customTextureWidth, customTextureHeight, 32, RenderTextureFormat.ARGB32, RenderTextureReadWrite.Default );

    Material blitMaterial = new Material( Shader.Find( "Diffuse Detail" ) );
    blitMaterial.SetColor( "_Color", Color.white );
    blitMaterial.SetTexture( "_MainTex", pattern1 );
    blitMaterial.SetTexture( "_Detail", pattern2 );
    Graphics.Blit( pattern1, customDressTexture, blitMaterial );

    return customDressTexture;
}
```